# A full head of hair vs a head full of hair

Tags: difference, usage

Someone who has a lot of hair on their head is said to have a [**full head of hair**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full%20head%20of%20hair). The order of the words, I must admit, struck me as strange when I first saw the phrase (just as *a full man of pride* would be strange). If I said

> Jack has a head full of hair.

Would that be equally correct?

Answer (score 2):

A man with **a full head of hair**. That is an idiom meaning the man has no hair loss.

**A woman with a full basket of supplies.** This isn't. It's just descriptive, and contrasts with the more usual usage: with a basket full of supplies.

Generally, the full modifies a noun and the second noun is genitive.

A politician with a **full bag of tricks**. [though bag full of tricks is also said]. This would be a politician who knows all the tricks, so to speak.

Now, a man with a **head full of hair** cannot be criticized for not being grammatical but due to the idiomatic usage given above re head and hair, **it is comical**.

Why is this comical? Because we also have:

**A child with a head full of lice**;

**A man with a head full of ideas**.

To have a head full of something is idiomatic, in general. But, in the case of having all one's hair, we do say: a full head of hair. English is quirky that way.

So, if  you hear: a man with a head full of hair, you automatically would think: Oh, so he isn't a man with a head full of [something else, like ideas etc.] and that expectation makes it funny.

Comment: If I heard someone say that a person had a "head full of hair", I would first imagine that they meant that the person's skull was stuffed full of hair in place of brain matter, blood vessels, etc, and then I would decide that they really meant "full head of hair". When I was young, cushions and seats were often stuffed with horsehair.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Precisely, and that would be comical. Like the poor Scarecrow in the Wizard of Oz whose head was stuffed with straw and whose ardent wish was get himself a real brain.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you think is "comical".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey A good sense of humor is nice, and to funny things may entice, but some are just full of things hairy and prefer to be really all scary.

Answer (score 1):

The head is a complicated thing.   It is a container. It is a surface.   And especially if it has hair, it is an ecosystem.

> Jack has a head full of ideas.
>
> Jack has a head full of lice.
>
> Jack has a full head of hair.

A "head full of hair" would be understood, but it's not the usual collocation.